# Serve images in Laravel with Quick Admin installed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-admin

I've installed Quick Admin under new Laravel project. There are few images in `public/images` folder that need to be served. I'm using `{{asset('images/myImage.jpg')}}` command to insert web path into `src` attribute of `img` tag.

Problem is that for some images I'm getting correct image as it should be, but for the rest of the images (for most of them) I'm getting following error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

All of the images are valid images and I can open them using any Photo Viewer. I'm using Laravel 5.5. my `web` and `api` route files are almost empty. Feel free to ask for any additional infos or resources.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? Any chance it's a case-sensitivity issue? Depending on your OS, IMAGE.jpg might not the same as image.jpg.

Comment: @Tudor Case-sensitivity is not an issue, I checked that zillion times. Permissions are not the problem too, because I checked it to, and all files have same permissions and some of them are serving good, but others throw the error.

Comment: Could you attach a few URLs that work and a few that don't? Maybe there's some sort of pattern.. not sure what else to suggest. It has to be some small oversight, no reason why just some would work and others not.

Comment: @Tudor /images/Multimedija.jpg is working and /images/C1.jpg is not.